# How come it's like this?

Tags: javascript, jquery

[***`http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/whY4B/`***](http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/whY4B/)

```
$("p").each(function(i) {
    var btn = $('<button>button</button>'),
        span = $('<span>span</span>');
    $(this).after(btn).after(span);
});​
```

So here I have `<p>`s in my HTML and I use `.after()` to create buttons and spans:

```
$(this).after(btn).after(span);
```

`btn` comes first, and `span` comes last. But the result is the opposite: `btn` comes last, and `span` comes first.

What the heck? How come it's like that and it is very confusing. Please help.

Comment: why not .append() or appendTo() ?

Comment: And why split the variables? Make the button and span one variable and append it.

Comment: Be careful with `body.after` in your fiddle, the `p`s are being placed outside the `body`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`.after()` method](http://api.jquery.com/after/) inserts the element passed as a parameter immediately after the element you call it on. So in your code the first `.after()` inserts `btn` such that it immediately follows your `<p>` and then the second call inserts `span` so that it immediately follows your `<p>`.

Obviously the fix for this is to add them in the opposite order.

Note that the result will be:

```
<p>your para content</p>
<button>button</button>
<span>span</span>
```

I.e., the new elements really are added *after* and not as children of your paragraph. If you use `.append()` it will add them as children, so

```
$(this).append(btn).append(span);

// will give you

<p>your original para content
   <button>button</button>
   <span>span</span>
</p>

// (indenting added just for clarity)
```

Note also that if you are adding exactly the same content to each paragraph you don't need the `.each()` because this will do it too:

```
var ele = $('<button>button</button>'),
    span = $('<span>span</span>');

$("p").after(span).after(ele);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nnnnnn/whY4B/7/

Comment: @elclanrs: Ha! I was bound to "win" eventually... Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

It's like that because [`after`](http://api.jquery.com/after/) inserts your content but returns the original element, the paragraph. So your code is saying "insert this button after the p" then "insert this span after the p" (which also happens to be before the button).

To get what you want, pass both items to `after`:

```
$(this).after(btn,span);
```

Comment: Oh, I don't know I can do `.after(ele,span)`.